# TailwindCSS custom theme don't works with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I've installed `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` from create nuxt-app, i modified the `tailwind.config.js` file with my value :

```js
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  theme: {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        fontFamily: {
          one: ["Arial", "Poppins", "Raleway"],
          two: ["Muli", "Open Sans"]
        },
        screens: {
          xll: "1400px"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

This config don't works when i apply the `font-one` class to an element, nothing happen

editor:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-tailwindcss-bhc5n

Can someone help me ? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double "theme" in Your config. That's why it's not working.

```
  theme: {
    theme: {
```